# Excel VBA insert row plus copy last row formula

Tags: excel

Formula below just inserts the row and changing color for certain offset. I need to copy formula from previuos cells H, M, N. Any ideas?

```
Sub button()
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
Range("D" & LastRow + 1).EntireRow.Insert
With Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    .Value = .Offset(-1).Value + 1
    .Offset(, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    .Offset(, -2).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    .Offset(, -3).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So now it's working

Sub Prideti_produkta()

```
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
Range("D" & LastRow + 1).EntireRow.Insert
Range("H" & LastRow + 1).FillDown
Range("K" & LastRow + 1).FillDown
Range("M" & LastRow + 1).FillDown
Range("N" & LastRow + 1).FillDown

With Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    .Value = .Offset(-1).Value + 1
    .Offset(, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    .Offset(, -2).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    .Offset(, -3).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
End With


End Sub
```